# How do I create a wireless linux router from a spare server?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, sniffing

I'm going to be doing some experiments with network traffic sniffing and I would like to setup a linux box as my home router. Are there any really easy ways to do this and have a web-configurable panel like a commodity router? I found a link for ClarkConnect, but no in-depth HOWTOs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [pfSense](http://pfsense.org) it has many [features](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=40&Itemid=43):

- Firewall
- Network Address Translation (NAT)
- Redundancy
- Load Balancing
  Reporting and Monitoring
- RRD Graphs

  The RRD graphs in pfSense maintain historical information on the following.

  - CPU utilization
  - Total throughput
  - Firewall states
  - Individual throughput for all interfaces
  - Packets per second rates for all interfaces
  - WAN interface gateway(s) ping response times
  - Traffic shaper queues on systems with traffic shaping enable
- **VPN**

  - IPsec
  - PPTP
  - OpenVPN
- Dynamic DNS

  Through:

  - DynDNS
  - DHS
  - DyNS
  - easyDNS
  - No-IP
  - ODS.org
  - ZoneEdit
- Captive Portal
- DHCP Server and Relay

It has a nice, easy to use web-based configuration, just look at the [screen-shots](http://www.pfsense.org/screenshots/).

There are also some nice [tutorials](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Tutorials).

Best of all you can build it yourself with commodity hardware, and it's [Open Source](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=site%3Apfsense.org%20license%20pfsense).

Answer (score 2):

There are several distros capable of this.

- [Pfsense](http://www.pfsense.com/)
- [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php)
- [IPcop](http://www.ipcop.org/)